# C++ Server program error

Tags: c++, sockets

I have been following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBAAbp6cNpg
for programming a server in c/c++ and its giving my this error :

9 C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\C++-Workspace\main.cpp undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

and it is on this line and I have no idea what to make of it any suggestions??

```
answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION,&wsaData);//The version of the DLL
```

Comment: Are you linking against `Ws2_32.lib`? That's where `WSAStartup` is at, and your error is an 'undefined reference' error (meaning the linker can't find `WSAStartup` in the libraries you currently are linking against) (`WSAStartp` link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @txtechhelp I linked it doing this in my header file that I created is this how you would do it in dev c++? :#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib");